# Response date fucntion

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date

I want to obtain the response date (number of days) based on other parameters. Used to use an excel file for document management, trying to upgrade to sharepoint and use meta-data.

The formula i'm trying to implement is:

```
IF([A]>0, [A]-[B],IF(AND(ISBLANK([A]), ISBLANK([B])), "", [C]-[B]))
```

Where,

- A=Date returned from the client,
- B=Date issued to client,
- C=Current date.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps.

```
IF([A]>0,DATEDIF([B], [A],"d"),IF(AND(ISERROR([A]), ISERROR([B])), "", DATEDIF([B], [C],"d")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF([A]>0,DATEDIF([B], [A],"d"),IF(AND(ISBLANK([A]), ISBLANK([B])), "", DATEDIF([B], [C],"d")))
```

Date and time formulas for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#date-and-time-formulas